# Calendar Provider URI Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-calendar

I try to get Calendar in Calendar Provider. Actually It works fine on Samsung Nexus S (4.1.2). Here are code :

```
cur = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), null, "((calendar_id  = ?) AND (_id = ?))",  new String[]{String.valueOf(CalendarId), eventId}, null);
```

But cursor count is alway  0 in Samsung Galaxy Note (4.0.4) (SHV-E160S). Does anyone has this issue ?

Thanks for your reading!

Comment: I reslove it now, Start the debugger and extract its data to find column name, Different column name on different kind of phone...It spends me a day